# c++ boost read wrong data from socket

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I try to use boost ssl socket server. I get the example from https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/ssl/server.cpp and try to cout receive data:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
public:
    session(tcp::socket socket, boost::asio::ssl::context& context)
        : socket_(std::move(socket), context)
    {
    }

    void start()
    {
        do_handshake();
    }

private:
    void do_handshake()
    {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        socket_.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::server,
            [this, self](const boost::system::error_code& error)
            {
                if (!error)
                {
                    do_read();
                }
            });
    }

    void do_read()
    {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_),
            [this, self](const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t length)
            {
                if (!ec)
                {
                    std::cout << std::string(data_) << std::endl;

                    do_write(length);
                }
            });
    }

    void do_write(std::size_t length)
    {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data_, length),
            [this, self](const boost::system::error_code& ec,
                std::size_t /*length*/)
            {
                if (!ec)
                {
                    do_read();
                }
            });
    }

    boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket> socket_;
    char data_[1024];
};

class server
{
public:
    server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, unsigned short port)
        : acceptor_(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)),
        context_(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23)
    {
        context_.set_options(
            boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds
            | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2
            | boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
        context_.set_password_callback(std::bind(&server::get_password, this));
        context_.use_certificate_chain_file("/home/chiffa/SOAP/CRT/Server.crt");
        context_.use_private_key_file("/home/chiffa/SOAP/CRT/Server.key", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
        context_.use_tmp_dh_file("/home/chiffa/SOAP/CRT/dh2048.pem");

        do_accept();
    }

private:
    std::string get_password() const
    {
        return "test";
    }

    void do_accept()
    {
        acceptor_.async_accept(
            [this](const boost::system::error_code& error, tcp::socket socket)
            {
                if (!error)
                {
                    std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket), context_)->start();
                }

                do_accept();
            });
    }

    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    boost::asio::ssl::context context_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {


        boost::asio::io_context io_context;

        using namespace std; // For atoi.
        server s(io_context, atoi("4443"));

        io_context.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Then I send from POSTMAN some JSON data, like:

```json
{
    "cmd": "alerts",
    "endpoint": "ref/alerts",
    "lng_id": 1
}
```

But on cout I get this:

```
POST /ref/alerts HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 545be9f7-8d3f-4f7e-ba44-e3a38d648031
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.6.0
Accept: */*
Host: 192.168.1.229:4443
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 70
Connection: keep-alive

{
    "cmd": "alerts",
    "endpoint": "ref/alerts",
    "lng_id": 1
}flate, br

Content-Length: 51

FHaIuRqCKdojreapq3ziIChnhxJ5Lllt1kgJbhSVxQbnpB5967wNASYNyM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!
```

Can anyone explain why it adds `flate, br Content-Length: 51  FHaIuRqCKdojreapq3z......` and how to fix it?

Comment: Are both the server and client under development? If so, you could replace the client end with a simple `curl` call just to test the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `session` class, the `data_` member is a simple `char[]` array, thus when `do_read()` calls `std::string(data_)`, the `std::string` constructor treats `data_` as a null-terminated C string, reading until it finds a `'\0'` char in memory.

But, `data_` is not a null-terminated C string.  If a `'\0'` char is not found within the bytes that `async_read_some()` wrote into `data_` (which will never be found in this example), then the `std::string` will simply read into the rest of the `data_` memory and you end up outputting whatever was already present in `data_` that `async_read_some()` did not overwrite.  But worse, if no `'\0'` is found before the end of `data_` is reached, the `std::string` will keep reading into surrounding memory, and now you have a buffer overflow.

The `length` parameter of the `async_read_some()` predicate is the actual number of bytes saved into `data_`.  Use the `std::string` constructor that accepts a length as an input parameter:

`std:::cout << std::string(data_, length);`

Or, you can get rid of the `std::string` altogether by using the `ostream::write()` method instead:

`std::cout.write(data_, length);`

Comment: Yep no need for the `std::string`. Was already formulating a comment before I saw the final two lines :P

Comment: now it's work fine, but I have a "history" of my req, like:

`code`POST /ref/alerts?rnd=3284ref/alerts?rnd=1883ref/alerts?rnd=1232ref/alerts?rnd=955ref/alerts?rnd=6144ref/alerts?rnd=4035ref/alerts?rnd=6524ref/alerts?rnd=9125ref/alerts?rnd=8816ref/alerts?rnd=2291ref/alerts?rnd=3124ref/alerts?rnd=3686ref/alerts?rnd=8345 HTTP/1.1

Host: 192.168.1.229:4443

.....
{"endpoint":"ref/alerts","cmd":"alerts","lng_id":1}`code`
last request was: ref/alerts?rnd=8345...

Comment: @НиколайДеменков that would have to be happening on the client side not the server side. The server is just outputting whatever the client sends. Also, don't use `code` to mark code snippets in comments, use backticks (`) instead. See [Markdown Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) particularly [Comment formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).